# Install PYQT using python with -g option, centos

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, maya

I don't use Linux because I'm a fairly average computer user/programmer. However, for work, I need to compile scripts using Linux - so color me frustrated.

I am trying to install PYQT using the script found here: https://github.com/cyrillef/Maya-PyQt-Scripts/blob/v2016.5/linux/pyqt

I am using Maya 2017, that's really the only difference. But the lines near the end seems to be giving me an error I just can't get around. The lines are

```
export PATH=$QTDIR/bin:$PATH
$QTDIR/bin/mayapy ./configure.py LIBDIR_QT=$LIBDIR_QT INCDIR_QT=$INCDIR_QT MOC=$QTDIR/bin/moc -w --no-designer-plugin -g
```

The problem I'm getting is with that pesky -g option. Here is the error output:

```
configure.py: error: no such option: -g
```

I'm loath to just remove the option because if it successfully builds with the wrong options then I end up with a broken installation and there's no way someone like me could fix it.

I am using Centos 7, Python 2.7.5 (I tried installing 2.7.13 like 3 times, but it just doesn't seem to stick whenever I do Python -V), and Maya 2017.

Does anybody know how to make this install? And if you do, please point me to instructions that describe the operations in a way that a 5 year-old could understand and follow (I'm absolutely sick of having to guess which directory I'm supposed to be in at any given time, or if there are 50 dependencies that I'm missing).

Comment: Why do you want pyqt with maya2017 ? .. its already shipping with PySide2 .. which has everything same as PyQt

Comment: That's a script for PyQt4, you're apparently trying to build PyQt5?  It's going to have different build options, check the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html).  Likely, you can skip the `-g` option..